# grails inheritance no discriminator

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I have the following problem in Domain class model.

I have a BaseDomainClass.

Which i use like this:

```
class ScheduleAction extends BaseDomainClass{
     ...
     static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
     }
}
```

this works fine. All the properties from by BaseDomainClass are written in the table of ScheduleAction.

The problem I am having now is

```
 class ScheduleActionAddActivityToPerson extends ScheduleAction{
    static mapping = {  
           tablePerHierarchy true
           discriminator column : 'TYP'
      }
 }
```

But i don't see the inheritance depicted in my database table.

I would like to see somtething like:

```
table ScheduleAction 
     id 
     version 
     typ
```

But I don't see "typ" field in my database. Can anybody give me a hint please?

Comment: Can you tell what are the tables created and their corresponding columns?

Comment: Do you have the 'typ' column defined?